# Concatenate Fasta files in R

Tags: r

I have multiple fasta formated nucleotide sequence files. I need to concatenate those files into one fasta file. Additionally I want to relabel those sequences accordingly.

Is there any R-package available or any executable software that can work in R?

Comment: Hello Furqan. Welcome to SO. Please read [How to Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and update your question accordingly.

Comment: Better suited on https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `read.fasta()` function from the [seqinr package](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/seqinr/versions/3.4-5/topics/read.fasta) is used to read fasta-formatted files.

The output of this function is a list containing vectors of characters. These lists can be combined into a single list in R with a function such as `c()`. The data can be manipulated with other functions from the `seqinr` package.

If you post some sample data from a couple of files or a link to some sample data in your original post, I can illustrate how to concatenate the files.

In the meantime, here is some example code illustrating how to read a set of raw data text vectors with `readLines()` and combine them to a single list.

```
file1 <- "aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd"

file2 <- "eee
fff
ggg
hhh"

file3 <- "iii
jjj
kkk
lll"

file4 <- "mmm
nnn
ooo"

list1 <- lapply(c(file1,file2),function(x){readLines(textConnection(x))})
list2 <- lapply(c(file3,file4),function(x){readLines(textConnection(x))})
c(list1,list2)
```

...and the output:

```
> c(list1,list2)
[[1]]
[1] "aaa" "bbb" "ccc" "ddd"

[[2]]
[1] "eee" "fff" "ggg" "hhh"

[[3]]
[1] "iii" "jjj" "kkk" "lll"

[[4]]
[1] "mmm" "nnn" "ooo"

>
```

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but has good SEO in Google so here's a new answer:

There's a package called EnvNJ that has a specific function for this exactly.
See fastaconc() in EnvNJ package: https://rdrr.io/cran/EnvNJ/man/fastaconc.html