# How to merge FASTA files in R

Tags: r, merge, bioinformatics, fasta

I have four separate FASTA files that I'd like to merge into one large FASTA file. So far I've used the Biostrings package to read each file separately

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49841921/concatenate-fasta-files-in-r

Comment: not a good solution if your fasta file is huge, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59792855/loading-fasta-file-in-r-faster-than-when-using-read-fasta-from-seqinr/59827889#59827889

Comment: Biostrings is ok, how did you store the fasta files?

Answer (score 1):

For example if your fasta files are:

```
folder = "http://hgdownload.soe.ucsc.edu/goldenPath/sacCer3/chromosomes/"
files = paste0(folder,c("chrI","chrII","chrIII","chrIV"),".fa.gz")
files
[1] "http://hgdownload.soe.ucsc.edu/goldenPath/sacCer3/chromosomes/chrI.fa.gz"  
[2] "http://hgdownload.soe.ucsc.edu/goldenPath/sacCer3/chromosomes/chrII.fa.gz" 
[3] "http://hgdownload.soe.ucsc.edu/goldenPath/sacCer3/chromosomes/chrIII.fa.gz"
[4] "http://hgdownload.soe.ucsc.edu/goldenPath/sacCer3/chromosomes/chrIV.fa.gz"
```

And we can do:

```
library(Biostrings)
fa_seq = lapply(files,readDNAStringSet)
fa_seq = do.call(c,fa_seq)
fa_seq

  A DNAStringSet instance of length 4
      width seq                                             names               
[1]  230218 CCACACCACACCCACACACCCA...GTGTGGGTGTGGTGTGTGTGGG chrI
[2]  813184 AAATAGCCCTCATGTACGTCTC...TGGGTGTGGTGTGTGGGTGTGT chrII
[3]  316620 CCCACACACCACACCCACACCA...TGTGGTGGGTGTGGTGTGTGTG chrIII
[4] 1531933 ACACCACACCCACACCACACCC...AAAGGTAGTAAGTAGCTTTTGG chrIV
```